# Storage allocator - what is it?

Tags: c++, memory

I know of storage classes in both C and C++ (static, extern, auto, register, C++ also adds mutable and some compiler-specific ones) but I can't figure out what a **storage allocator** is. I don't think it's referred to memory allocators implementable on STL, what is it in simple terms?

Comment: Can you tell us where/in what context you heard/saw the term used? I don't believe the phrase is used widely enough to have a meaning that's well defined all by itself.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - 17.1[library.general] /6 in C++11. 20.1 [lib.utilities]/1 in C++03.

Comment: I have never heard of storage allocated before now. At least in C, there is no such formal term. A text search through the C standard mentions it only once, in non-normative next. A storage allocator is apparently the algorithm which allocates memory dynamically.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That certainly *could* be what he's referring to -- I'm a bit hesitant to assume it though (but maybe that's just me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's whatever is behind `operator new` and `operator delete` (not to be confused with the `new` operator and the `delete` operator). `operator new` allocates memory from the free store, and `operator delete` releases memory previously allocated by `operator new` for possible reuse. When code does `foo *ptr = new foo` (`new` operator), the compiler generates code that calls `operator new` to get the right number of bytes of storage, then calls the constructor for `foo`. When code does `delete ptr` (`delete` operator) the compiler calls the destructor for `foo`, then calls `operator delete` to release the memory.

Note that this is how the term is used in the C++03 standard. In the C++11 standard it is **also** used to refer to standard allocators.

Comment: That's the *free store*, not a storage allocator.

Comment: As I said, that is the free store. The standard also refers to it as a "storage allocator" in the library section, 17.1[library.general]/6.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my comment was overly pedantic. "Storage allocator" isn't a formally defined term, and the standard does indeed use it in one place in relation to the free store.

Comment: The **C++11** standard uses it in two different ways. In **C++03** it was used **only** to refer to the free store.

Answer (score 5):

In the C++ standard, that term is used to refer to the allocator class used by STL-style containers - either `std::allocator`, or a user-defined custom allocator that meets the requirements given by C++11 17.6.3.5.

However, it's not a formally defined term, and also appears once referring to the implementation of the free store - that is, the dynamic storage allocated by `new`.

[NOTE: I'm referring to the current (2011) language specification. As noted in the comments, historical versions of the specification apparently only used the term (informally) to refer to the free store]

Comment: That's one of the two uses in C++11; the other is to the free store. C++03 used it **only** to refer to the free store.

Comment: Well, it's not "formally" defined in that there's nothing that says "storage allocator means...". However, it is quite clearly defined when it is used: "The general utilities library (Clause 20) includes components used by other library elements, such as a predefined **storage allocator** for dynamic storage management (3.7.4)" (emphasis added). And 3.7.4 discusses `operator new` and `operator delete`, **not** allocators.

Comment: @PeteBecker: And just as clearly defined (or rather, not defined), when it's also used to refer to STL-style allocators: "17.6.3.5 describes the requirements on **storage allocators**". It's an informal term, used in different places to refer to different things.

Comment: Yes, it's used both ways in C++11, but **not** in C++03. That's what I've said several times.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Fair enough; I'm talking specifically about the current C++ standard, not historic versions.

Comment: On the contrary: "predefined **storage allocators** for dynamic storage management (3.7.4)" **is** a definition. It means that "storage allocator" refers to the thing behind the operations discussed in 3.7.4.

Comment: @PeteBecker: OK; but in that case, it has two contradictory definitions, in which case it is very much not defined. But this argument is getting far too pedantic for me. The current standard uses the term informally to refer to two different things; in the past, things might have been different, but that's not relevant to the present.

Comment: There's no contradiction. In C++11 it has two meanings. In C++03 it had one.